# Script not working fully under systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, python

I have a python script to switch light/dark mode.

At the end there's this line:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(binDir + "/polybar.sh")
```

That script it points to is this:

```
#!/bin/env bash

# Terminate already running bar instances
killall -q polybar
polybar >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

If I execute the light/dark script from terminal it works perfectly, polybar gets killed and then relaunched.

However, I want a service to automatically switch depending on the time of the day, so I made some systemd timers. The light/dark script gets executed, most of the stuff in it works, but this in particular doesn't, it just kills polybar and it doesn't launch again. The systemd service is a user service.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this, `systemctl status` is not providing any info.

Why would a script work fine when launched from terminal, but not from systemd?

Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Type=simple
Description=dark mode
Environment="PATH=/home/{{ user }}/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/{{ user }}/bin"
WorkingDirectory=/home/{{ user }}/bin

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/brightnessctl s 200
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/ger/bin/nutra.py dark
```

And the timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn screen dark/light at certain times

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 18:13:00
Persistent=true


[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: How is `bindir` defined in the python script and is `$PATH`  set differently between the systemd and interactive environments?

Comment: `binDir = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/bin"`

After reading a stackexchange answer, I added this to the systemd service:

`Environment="PATH=/home/{{ user }}/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/{{ user }}/bin"`

However it didn't help.

Comment: `The light/dark script gets executed, most of the stuff in it works, but this in particular doesn't, it just kills polybar and it doesn't launch again. The systemd service is a user service. I don't know how to troubleshoot this, systemctl status is not providing any info.` To properly answer that you should provide the contents of both the timer and service units you used.\
My educated guess is that you used `RemainAfterExit=true` in the service file.

Comment: I don't know polybar. You could redirect the polybar output to a file, to see the messages, and post it here (e.g. run `polybar > /home/username/polybar.log` instead of `polybar &>/dev/null`). Most GUI applications require the environment var `DISPLAY=:0` Try to add `export DISPLAY=:0` to your shell script below the shebang.

Comment: Maybe `polybar --reload` is enough to reload new settings ... To get the results with  `journalctl -t polybar`. Run `polybar --reload | systemd-cat -t polybar`

Comment: @MichaelD.I think that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or startup scripts, or `systemd` scripts, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. Startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
An easy way is to store the commands in a `bash` script, and execute it from your terminal session, saving the output, then, execute the script from the "other" environment, saving the output. Compare the saved outputs using `diff`.

```
echo "=== id ===";id
echo "=== set ===";set
echo "=== env ===";env | sort
echo "=== alias ===";alias`
```