# Asterisk pbx agi php script with imagick imaging on the fly not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, asterisk

#### Problem description:

Generate an image with an ASTERISK AGI PHP script that is displayed on a phone (Yealnk) using `imagick`.

```
installed:php-imagick/oldstable,now 3.4.4+php8.0+3.4.
```

The AGI PHP script consists of two parts:

1 Generating an image containing caller information, such as telephone number and a corresponding passport photo based on the telephone number.

2 Send this image to the phone.

#### What works in the PHP script?

2: Send an existing image to the phone.

If I use an existing image, it is sent to the phone and displayed without any problems.

#### What doesn't work in the PHP script:

1: No image is generated with imagick.

In the Asterisk CLI I see that the script is executed with a `0`, so no error messages.

---

If I start the script as root in `/usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin` then everything works fine. Imagick generates an image and it is neatly delivered to the phone:

```
php script.php 01234567
```

But as soon as the script calls imagick it stops working, like this: $foto = new Imagick("/path/to/image/image.png");

#### What have I tried:

1 Used other image generators: `gdimage` and `gmagick`, but they have the same problem.

2 `chown 777 script.php`

3 Check whether Asterisk is passing the correct variables (that works fine) with the AGI command

4 Start PHP script in the CLI as another user (`su otheruser`) imagick does not work either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why imagick isn't generating images from an AGI in Asterisk?

UPDATE:
Ok, I've made some progress. I suspect it is a read and write permission case. When I write to /tmp, the script does not stop and indeed an image is written to /tmp. Reading that picture still causes problems. I continue searching.

Comment: My answer `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755631/script-not-working-fully-under-systemd/755867#755867` might help.

Comment: OK thanks. I will look into your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some fiddling I found a hopefully safe solution. I added asterisk to the www-data group and now asterisk php agi with imagick writes the image without any problems and I can easily send it to the phone. Everything works as it should.

(Thanks waltinator for your input!)